# SQL Pivot Table On A Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

I am trying to do a pivot table using a common table expression, but my pivot table is returning NULL values in the pivoted columns. When I select * from cte, my results return just as I would expect. I could use some help figuring out why my pivot table isn't working correctly.

My common table expression joins two tables that look like this:

#### ProductionLine

```
ID | ProductionLine
--------------------
1  | Line A
2  | Line B
```

#### ProductionData

```
ID | ProductionLine_ID | UnitsProduced | ProductionDate
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1                 | 200           | 2014-09-18
2  | 2                 | 50            | 2014-09-18
3  | 1                 | 100           | 2014-09-19
```

#### All IDs are int fields. UnitsProduced is an int field. ProductionDate is a datetime field

#### Here is my sql query

```
;with cte as (select pl.ProductionLine as ProductionLine, pd.ProductionDate as ProductionDate, pd.UnitsProduced as UnitsProduced 
from ProductionLine pl
join
ProductionData pd on pl.ID = pd.ProductionLine_ID
)

select * from 
(
    select ProductionLine, 
    ProductionDate, 
    UnitsProduced
    from  cte
) x
pivot
(
    max(UnitsProduced) 
    for ProductionLine in ([Line A])
) pvt
```

I should get a result that looks like this:

```
ProductionDate | Line A
-----------------------
2014-09-18     | 200
2014-09-19     | 100
```

However, my result looks like this:

```
ProductionDate | Line A
-----------------------
2014-09-18     | NULL
2014-09-19     | NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks for adding that detail!  It would make a great edit - click the word 'edit' under your question, go down to the tags, and type in "sql-server-2008-r2" to add it.

Comment: Thank you. I've added sql-server-2008-r2 to the tags

Comment: @CameronWoodall Well sql fiddle appears to be down, but I tested your query and it is working just fine.  Are you sure you have the correct name for the new column - `Line A` - it has to match or you'll get `null`?  Here is a demo -- http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/227490

Comment: I tried your script, it show the result you expected. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely common to see select clause do something like this if data has NULLs:

SELECT **ISNULL([FieldName],0)** as [FieldName] FROM SOMTEABLE

Well it's no different for a query using `PIVOT`, you still solve the issue of NULLs through the `SELECT clause` although one problem here is that you have used "select *" and **this shortcut hides the positions where you can solve the problem.**

Syntax using a CTE. Note what was "select *" is now detailed, and `ISNULL(.....,0)` used.

```
;WITH
      cte
      AS (
            SELECT
                  pl.ProductionLine AS ProductionLine
                , pd.ProductionDate AS ProductionDate
                , pd.UnitsProduced  AS UnitsProduced
            FROM ProductionLine pl
                  JOIN ProductionData pd
                              ON pl.ID = pd.ProductionLine_ID
            )

SELECT
      ISNULL([Line A], 0) [Line A]
    , ISNULL([Line B], 0) [Line B]
FROM (
      SELECT
            ProductionLine
          , ProductionDate
          , UnitsProduced
      FROM cte
      ) x
PIVOT
      (
      MAX(UnitsProduced)
      FOR ProductionLine IN ([Line A], [Line B])
      ) pvt
;
```

Personally I don't recommend using CTE's unless there is a demonstrated need for it, which isn't true here and a simple subquery will do exactly the same job with slightly simpler syntax.

```
SELECT
      ISNULL([Line A], 0) [Line A]
    , ISNULL([Line B], 0) [Line B]
FROM (
      SELECT
            pl.ProductionLine AS ProductionLine
          , pd.ProductionDate AS ProductionDate
          , pd.UnitsProduced  AS UnitsProduced
      FROM ProductionLine pl
            JOIN ProductionData pd
                        ON pl.ID = pd.ProductionLine_ID
      ) x
PIVOT
      (
      MAX(UnitsProduced)
      FOR ProductionLine IN ([Line A], [Line B])
      ) pvt
;
```

<kbd>[See this working at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf9902/5)</kbd>

**`COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()`**

I have used ISNULL() in the above which is TSQL specific, and so is the PIVOT syntax. Stackoverflow recommend using standard SQL if possible so please note it would be possible to use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()` in the queries above. But also note those functions are not exactly the same.

Comment: This post has good information, so I'm marking it as the answer.